# Elastic Search : "fuzzy_like_this_field" filter query is not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, full-text-search, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am facing below issue in elastic search filter:

When I try to apply "fuzzy_like_this_field" on String value then it's working fine.

But when I apply "fuzzy_like_this_field" filter on different data type other than String(e.g double,Date) it's not working.

It gives

> ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[fuzzy_like_this_field doesn't support binary/numeric fields.

Please see below elastic search query

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"fuzzy_like_this_field": {"Receipts.retailerId": {"like_text": "55f5878916c042cc8731a39e4e05b7a0","fuzziness":0.3}}},{"fuzzy_like_this_field": {"Receipts.totalCost": {"like_text": "10","fuzziness":0.3}}}],"must_not": [],"should": []}},"from": 0,"size": 1000,"sort": [],"facets": {}}
```

Where retailerId - String and totalCost - double

if I change totalCost data type double to string then it works.

So please suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzy queries expand text search results to include terms a certain [Levenshtein Distance](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from the query term.  They expand numeric values by a margin *-fuzziness <= value <= +fuzzyiness* (The number of characters needed to be changed or transposed to match) - However, `fuzzy_like_this` and `fuzzy_like_this_field` only seem to support string matching (via Levenshtein distance).

---

`fuzzy_like_this` and `fuzzy_like_this_field` queries are deprecated in ES 1.6+.  And they both suffer from performance issues.  You should find another method for accomplishing your goal.

There are a number of ways to apply fuzzy matching, but I'm not sure fuzzy matching is what you're after.

By specifying:

```
"fuzzy_like_this_field":{  
                  "Receipts.retailerId":{  
                     "like_text":"55f5878916c042cc8731a39e4e05b7a0",
                     "fuzziness":0.3
                  }
               }
```

You're asking to match all `retailerId`s which match the `like_text` with up to 22 edits.   `Edit distance = length(term) * (1.0 - fuzziness) = 32 * 0.7 = 22.4`

So in this case `55ddddddd6c0ddddddd1a3dddddddda0` would qualify as a fuzzy match to `55f5878916c042cc8731a39e4e05b7a0` because 10 of the characters share the same position.

---

If, instead, you're merely looking for duplicate transactions, why not simply use a match query or filter, to match your `retailerId` and `totalCost` exactly?

```
"query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "Receipts.retailerId": "55f5878916c042cc8731a39e4e05b7a0" 
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "Receipts.totalCost": 10
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter...But I want to exact match..not a range..SO can you please suggest is there any other option

Comment: Fuzzy is used for close, but not necessarily exact matching.  Can you be more specific about your use-case?

Comment: Peter, Actually I want to filter all consumer receipt whose total cost is X amount and my totalCost variable is double type so how can I filtered those receipt because  fuzzy_like_this_field queries works only for string data